# Error converting data type varchar to date converting an int year into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SchoolYear variable as an INT, and I'm trying to set a variable to this:

```
SET @BeginDate = '07/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @SchoolYear - 1)
```

It gives me the 'Error converting data type varchar to date' error.

**Example:**

@SchoolYear INT = 2019,

@BeginDate Date - NULL

**Desired result:**

07/01/2018

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Try to set it in format **'yyyy-mm-dd'**

Comment: @jm1 Try to change @BeginDate datatype to `DATE`.

Comment: @iSR5, BeginDate is a date, I updated the question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JM1 execute this `SELECT GETDATE()` and check the date format for it, you should use the same date format as it appeared in the `GETDATE()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (available from SQL 2012), and bypass strings altogether.

```
SET @BeginDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@SchoolYear - 1, 1, 7)
```

1st arg = year, 2nd = month, 3rd = day.

Answer (score 2):

The format you are using is simply not understood by your sql server.

When dealing with dates in varchar columns/variables it is best to use a date format that is language neutral.
`yyyyMMdd` is such a format, it will always work no matter what regional settings are used on your server.

See also this http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

in your case you should use

```
SET @BeginDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @SchoolYear - 1) + '0107'
```

that is assuming that 01 is the month, and 07 is the day so you end up with `20180107`

Better would be off course to avoid varchar complete when converting, like this

```
set @BeginDate =  DATEFROMPARTS(@SchoolYear - 1, 1, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use the yyyy-mm-dd format and change the set as:

```
SET @BeginDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @SchoolYear - 1)+ '-01-07'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @SchoolYear int
Set @SchoolYear = 2019
Declare @BeginDate varchar(50)
SET @BeginDate = '07/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @SchoolYear - 1)    
--Once You have you varchar populated, you can use Convert Function to convert
--to datetime and select the format you want

Select CONVERT (Datetime,@BeginDate, 101)
```